# Bibliography header style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sectioning

Let's say I am using the following code (a sample example) to design the title format for the chapters.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries}          
{}                                   
{1pc}                                
{%

  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,flushright upper
    \resizebox{2cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
  \end{tcolorbox}\Huge} % before the title body
[]
```

This is working well for all chapters but it's also coming at the Bibliography section. How to remove or suppress it in the Bibliography heading? I am using the `natbib` package and using the following bib style:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibfile.bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Without a MWE ist is difficult to help you.  One suggestion would be, to redefine the `\titleformat` before issuing the `\bibliography` command.   Have you already tried that?

Comment: how to redefine the title format before \bibliography?

Comment: try to copy the first code block `\titleformat{...}` on top of the second code block, that it reads `\titleformat{...}\bibliographystyle{...} ...` Try to change the settings which bother you in this second definition of `\titleformat`

Comment: fine.  I am glad, I could help you.  Earn yourself some reputation points by answering your own question and mark it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by redefining the title format before the `\bibliography` command.

```
\titleformat{...}
\bibliographystyle{...}
```